# Does a graphics card decrease performance over time?

Tags: performance

I don't know where to ask this question exactly so I thought this was the best place to ask. Please close this question if this is somehow off-topic.

I have a year old ASUS G50VT-X5 and it has the following specs:

- Intel Core2 Duo P7450 (2.13GHz 3MB L2, 1066 FSB)
- nVidia GeForce 9800M GS 512MB DDR3 with PhyX support
- 4GB DDR2-6400 800MHz
- 320GB 7200RPM SATA

I used to be able to play games such as Heroes of Newerth and Allods Online with every setting on high without experiencing any FPS drop when I first bought my laptop. Nowadays, I experience occasional massive FPS drops while playing regardless of the settings (I still experience FPS drops even on the lowest settings possible).

I tried everything I can to increase my laptop's performance (Provide better cooling, update to the latest video card drivers) but no dice.

Is this because my laptop is getting old?

Comment: Clarifying question: the *same* games that used to run fine at high FPS now run terrible? Or *new* games run terrible at the same FPS?

Comment: The same games used to run fine on 60 fps at high settings but now runs terrible regardless of settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be because

- The developers of MMO you mention increased the detail being cranked out in the game
- Laptop vents are clogged
- Poor thermal contact between the heatsink and the thermal compound

> Is this because my laptop is getting old?

Perhaps, but not because the hardware is "slowing" down - might be because of above mentioned reasons

Comment: I have the EXACT same laptop as the asker, and had the EXACT same issue.  It was clogged vents causing the graphics card to overheat.  Had to pop the bottom off to an angle where I could blow the dust off with compressed air.  Note that there are tons of screws of different lengths holding the bottom panel on, so sketch the shape of the panel on a sheet of paper and push the screws through the appropriate space on the diagram as you take them out.

Comment: @TuxRug you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: So I should try to clean the insides of my laptop? Is that what I should do?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpCJzdWxEbQ

Comment: @ephemient that video is awesome!

Comment: @ephemient, that video made me cry. Is cleaning the fan really that complicated? I think I'm doomed to have an "expert" do it for me.

Comment: @Sathya: You had the answer, so I wouldn't feel right about posting an answer with what you said first. It'd be like trying to steal the rep.  You answered it first, you deserve the rep :)

Comment: @Terrence Ponce: On this computer, it's not really that difficult.  Just remove the battery then take a sheet of paper, sketch the bottom panel (this computer only has the one big one),take the screws out (just the ones on the panel) and put them in the correct place on your sketch to keep track, then pop off the panel.  It has some clips so you might need to pry a bit, but make sure all the screws are out, including the one in the middle of the panel.  Blow some compressed air at the fan and watch the cloud of dust emerge.  You don't need to unplug anything inside or remove the DVD drive.